# Copy bits from ulong to long in C#

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

So it appears that the [.NET performance counter type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) has an annoying problem: it exposes `long` for the counter RawValue while the actual perf counter value in windows is unsigned and cannot be negative. For instance if you have a NumberOfItems64 counter The API will be perfectly happy to accept a negative value, then silently convert it to a very large number. In fact for half the value range of the counter the only way to set it there is to find the correct negative value to pass in!

I assume what is happening here is that they are taking the raw bits from the `long` and treating it as an unsigned 64-bit number. The negative values from two's complement are just read as a straight up number for the counter.

So I'm trying to figure out how to coerce C# into just dropping the bits from the `ulong` straight into the `long`, since that's what the API wants. But C# is being too helpful here... you can't cast or use `Convert.ToInt64(ulong)` since it throws overflow exceptions because of the value being too large. I stumbled upon this way of doing the conversion:

`Convert.ToInt64(myULong.ToString("X"), 16)`

When it converts from a string in non-base 10 it assumes the number is in two's complement and does what I need it to. But it's not ideal because it needs to allocate an object and parse a string for every conversion and this API is going to be performance-critical. Is there a better way in C# to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of code which causes the overflow exception problem on a cast?  I can do `long signed = long.MaxValue;
signed++; ulong unsigned = (ulong)signed;` without exceptions.

Comment: @Will: Are you compiling with `/checked+` ?  The behavior could change.  Also, you could just say `ulong unsigned = (ulong)long.MinValue;` and `long signed = (long)ulong.MaxValue;`, both of which preserve bits but change the value.

Comment: @Ben - Good question - I'm just running Linqpad, so I'm not sure what it's settings are.

Comment: Okay got it working. I just need to do a cast inside an `unchecked` block.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple cast like

```
ulong value1 = 0xFEDCBA9876543210UL;  // 18364758544493064720
long value2 = (long)value1;           // -81985529216486896
ulong value3 = (ulong)value2;         // 18364758544493064720
```

preserves the bits in the value exactly.

Comment: No, I want to copy bits from a ulong to a long, not convert a long to a ulong.

Comment: This will do a binary conversion of the bits. Not sure why this is downvoted. Copying the bits is the same as converting. You might want to add `unchecked(...)`.

Comment: @usr I downvoted the original edit (before the ninja one that produced the current version), because the cast went in the wrong direction. +1 for `unchecked`.

Comment: Okay there we go... I thought I had tried the cast already and gotten an error but I guess I was mistaken!

Comment: And yeah it threw the OverflowException when compiled with overflow checking enabled. Putting it in the `unchecked` block as suggested fixed that.