# Printing a ulong value in Binary using Convert.ToString()

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the binary of a ulong number but it says that it cannot convert from ulong to bool.

The workaround is casting the ulong to long but, I just want to know can not it do this if it works fine with uint or long etc...

What does bool have to do here?

btw I have checked this, sorry if the question is a duplicate.
[C# not supported ulong to bin/oct/dec/hex string -> Convert.ToString(ulong, base)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191275/c-sharp-not-supported-ulong-to-bin-oct-dec-hex-string-convert-tostringulong)

```
ulong efvenvjnuskl = 18446744073709551615;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(efvenvjnuskl,2));
```

Comment: You didn't do what the duplicate suggested, which is to use a `long`, not a `ulong`, or cast your `ulong` to a `long`.  There is [no suitable overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-6.0) available for `Convert.ToString` that accepts `ulong` and `int` parameters.  Note that your numeric constant is too large of a positive number to store in a `long`.

Comment: Actually I did the cast I just did not show It to you, my question was why can not It work with ulong values(the method). Thank you for your answer, but why is there no suitable overload?

Comment: Because Microsoft didn't provide one.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(unchecked((long)efvenvjnuskl), 2));`