# ulong is not be stored correctly in LiteDatabse

Tags: litedb, ulong

I am now making a MMO game using Unity.
Also I am using the LiteDB to store users data.
UserModel looks like this.
[image: UserModel of my game]

Everything is working correctly except for the mUserOwnerClientId.
The variable type is ulong and I tried to store ulong.MaxValue.
But the stored value was -1 and when I tried to read from database, there was an error because ulong could not be less than zero.

[image: When I store ulong.MaxValue, it is stored as -1]

So I have a question here.

Does LiteDB support ulong storing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay I will edit the question.

Comment: Post code, not images of our links to code.

Comment: _"Does LiteDB support ulong storing?"_ - LiteDB has excellent [documentation](https://www.litedb.org/docs/data-structure/). Which indicates only signed long support. But nothing will stop you from storing a `byte[]`  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiteDB supports long by default, not ulong (unsigned).

But you can tell it how to handle the serialization and deserialization of a type it doesn't know with BsonMapper before using your database:

```
BsonMapper.Global.RegisterType<ulong>(
    unsignedLong => new BsonValue(unsignedLong.ToInt64WithSameBits()),
    bson => bson.AsInt64.ToUInt64WithSameBits()
);

/// <summary>
/// Extra methods for <see cref="ulong"/> type.
/// </summary>
public static class UInt64ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes the bits of the provided <see cref="ulong"/> value and returns them as a <see cref="long"/>, which might be a completely different number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056230/copy-bits-from-ulong-to-long-in-c-sharp .
    /// </remarks>
    public static long ToInt64WithSameBits(this ulong value)
    {
        return unchecked((long) value);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use queries you can use the BsonMapper again:

```
ulong playerID = 1234;
var query = Query.EQ(nameof(PlayerDocument.PlayerID), BsonMapper.Global.Serialize(playerID));
```